# non-static classes in static classes

Tags: c#, static

What is the rationale that non-static inner classes can be declared within a static class?

```
public static class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public B() { }
    }
}
```

As compared to the fact that non-static members and functions cannot be declared within a static class.

Comment: For a nice example: the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable` has several (non-static) inner classes.

Answer (score 3):

What about multiple instances of `B`? In that way, non-static classes nested in static classes are no different to regular non-static classes.

```
public static class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public B() { }
    }

    private static B b1 = new B();
    private static B b2 = new B();
}
```

See for a real-life example the static [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3) class, which contains some specific implementations as nested non-static classes.